# how to change the action of submit button after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, events

I want to change the submit button to call signout function after the user signed in

---

```
<html>
<head>
 /* Here I have the links for jQuery and bootstrap so, they are working properly
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="signIn(event)">
<input type="text" id="username" />
<input type="password" id="password" />
<input type="submit" id="connect_disconnect">
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function signIn() {
    code ....
    // Below I just change the caption of the submit button from 'Connect' to 
    // 'Disconnect'
    $("#connect_disconnect").text('Disconnect');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function signOut() {
    code...
    }
</script>

</html>
```

---

with the above code, when I click on submit button, it will call the signIn function even when I am already signed in. I want it to call signOut function when I am already signed it. any ideas?
Thanks in advance and please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply a "submit" event handler to your form, then run [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) you can prevent the form from submitting the native way and you can run any Javascript you want.

Below I've added a code example showing what you could do to capture the event.

*I try not to add too much philosophy into my answers, but I've decided to include an example of a linked Javascript file.*

---

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <form id="theForm">
    <input type="text" id="username" />
    <input type="password" id="password" />
    <input type="submit" id="connect_disconnect">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

#### Javascript (script.js)

```
(function() { // Create closure to avoid global-scoped variables

  var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm'); // Select the <form> element

  theForm.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission); // Bind event listener.

  function handleFormSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Keep the form from taking any further native action

    if( /* user is signed in */ )
      signOut();
    else
      signIn();
  }

  function signIn() {
    // Sign In Code
  }

  function signOut() {
    // Sign Out Code
  }

})(); // End closure
```

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help. Feel free to "select" this as the answer since it worked for you.

Comment: Sure but, where to select it the answer cause I can not find it. Thanks again

Comment: It's pretty sneaky. Looks like you found it. Thanks!